# How to get cover photo with the new Google Sign-In API in Android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

In the new Google Sign-In API, I can get the profile photo using the following lines:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {               
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount(); 
        String profilePhoto = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
    }
}
```

But, there is no method in the **account**  object to get the cover photo, so my question is : **how to get the cover photo ?**

Also, I want to get the **birthdate** and **phone number**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The `GoogleSignInAccount` class doesn't provide any methods for cover photo, birthdate or phone number. You can read more in the official documantation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount).

For `cover photo` and `birthdate` you can make an *authorized* GET request here:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and you will get them in `response.birthday` and `respone.cover.coverPhoto.url`

Bear in mind that if you don't have a birthday date set, the request won't return any. And regarding the phone number, the I don't think the API offers that information.

Comment: To get the phone number, the OP should make GET request to `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`, can [Try It here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it), more info at [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing)

Comment: What is the type of {API_Key} that required in this API ?

Comment: It's a key that it's used to authenticate your application to Google API's. Take a look here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862

Answer (score 1):

As @Vlad said `GoogleSignInAccount` class doesn't provide any methods to retrieve the cover photo.

So, after a succeeded Google SignIn you could use the `userId` and `API_KEY` to make a GET request to:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{id}?personFields=coverPhotos&key={GoogleApiKey}
```

Replace `{id}` with `userId` and `{GoogleApiKey}` with `API_KEY`

Comment: what is userId?

Comment: As I said in the post. `UserId` is the `Id` retrieved when you successfully singnin with Google SingIn.